# json Schema to use cannot be null; executing through ant

Tags: java, ant, rest-assured, json-schema-validator

I'm doing endpoint-testing using Rest_assured Framework. We are trying to validate json returned through json schema validation, but while executing through Ant I'm getting a `json Schema to use cannot be null` error.

Comment: The error message seems clear enough. Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

Is the JSON schema located in classpath? The classpath could be different when you're running the tests from ant and from your IDE.